# How can I install/run a Google Apps Script that I've forked on Github?

Tags: github, google-apps-script

If I fork someone's Google Apps Script project on Github, how can I install/run my own version? It seems to always install/run the original project.

For example, I forked: https://github.com/webdigi/GmailScheduler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct connection between the GitHub repository and the code which actually executes.  Apps Script executes on Google Drive, so the modified code must be on your Drive so you can test it.

To take your own copy of the script, first you must Create an empty Google Apps Script project on your drive (using the Create button as you would for a doc or a gsheet), then copy & paste the source from github into your new file.  You will now have a copy of the script on your Google Drive, which you can then modify, test and execute.  Use the "Publish..." menu in the Google script editor (on Google Drive) to deploy your copy as a web-app.

You may want to then update your forked copy of README.md to point to your copy of the script for clarity.

Comment: There are issues with your instructions: (1) what link in README.md are you talking about? Please be specific. If you mean https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw6hnnKGeG6xUsbRE9c3WSvJibTbaW88DP9f83e8lFnc1v1kL0/exec then that does not show any option to "Make a Copy" and also there is no "File menu" shown. (2) If I manually download the Github project and upload the folder to my Google Drive (thereby bypassing your first step which didn't specify the  link), I see no option to modify/test/execute/publish because the filetypes are apparently incorrect (ie, they aren't "Google Apps Scripts").

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the "link to source" in readme.md simply points back to the github.  Updating the answer.

Comment: This is unfortunately a very clumsy way (to copy and paste the contents of every file into a Google script file). Can I not just upload a .gs file and have it understood as a Google Apps script file? When I try this, it doesn't know what app to open it with, and doesn't give Google Apps Script Editor as an option -- even though I connected that app to Drive.

Comment: I agree it's clumsy but there is no way that I'm aware of to upload a .gs to Drive through the UI.   From my perspective the root of the issue is that the code is on github, giving the impression there is some way to easily transfer between github and Drive when there is not.   You could potentially use the Drive SDK to upload the .gs files programatically.    Once you have the code on Drive it is very easy to work with the code, make copies and manage the project entirely within the Drive ecosystem.

Comment: I didn't mean to upload directly from Github, I meant from my harddrive. But I get your point. Thanks for the answer.